# React Native push notifications iOS - number pending notifications

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I use React Push Notifications (https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) with localNotificationSchedule for launch notifications, but in iOS the number of push notifications is never destroyed.

Even if I select notifications the number doesn't go down...

This number: (in icon from desktop)

[image]

My code:

```
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";

var PushNotification = require("react-native-push-notification");

  PushNotification.configure({

    onRegister: function(token) {
      console.log("TOKEN:", token);
    },

    onNotification: function(notification) {
      console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);

        let num = 0;
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          num = notification.data.num;
        } else {
          num = notification.userInfo.num;
        }        

        switch(num) {

          case 1:
            NavigationService.navigate('OnePage');
            break;
          case 2:
            NavigationService.navigate('TwoPage');
            break;     
          default:
            NavigationService.navigate('Home');

      }

      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
      }
    },

    senderID: "YOUR GCM (OR FCM) SENDER ID",

    permissions: {
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true
    },

    popInitialNotification: true,


    requestPermissions: true    
  });

class IndexNavigator extends React.Component {
...
```

Apparently, according to the documentation this code should be correct, but even if I press the notifications and redirect me to the page I want. The number in the icon never decreases, it always increases.

Anyone know why this can happen?

Comment: did you try `PushNotificationIOS.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(number);
` check doc https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.54/pushnotificationios#setapplicationiconbadgenumber

Comment: @LukášŠálek This would have to be used if you wanted to manipulate it manually. You automatically wouldn't have to do it just by subtracting the number of pending notifications? 

What is it for this `notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);`

Comment: I am using OneSignal and Firebase (fcm) and I had to set badge's numbers manually ... One signal has value in request body for badge's if it should increase or set up number but it does not work for me ... I always set it up manually ...

Comment: @LukášŠálek I'm using localnotification and numer is up automatically, but if someone discart notification, how I know that I have to decrease this number?

Comment: I had the same problem :D and i didn't find any solution for that ... I reset badges icon every time when the user opens the app I set up 0